# External interrrupt always run

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, avr

In my reset interrupt I set up external interrupt (to react on button click). But interrupt handler code called without button clicking. Why? (Atmega8 microcontroller)

```
EXT_INT0:
ldi temp, 0b0000001
out PORTB, temp

ldi temp, 0b0000000
out PORTC, temp

reti

RESET:      
cli
ldi temp,HIGH(RAMEND) ; set stack register
out SPH,temp
ldi temp,LOW(RAMEND)
out SPL,temp    


ldi temp, (0<<ISC00)
out MCUCR, temp

ldi temp, (1<<INT0)
out GIMSK, temp

sei 
INNER_SICLE:
    rjmp INNER_SICLE
```

Comment: That's impossible to tell without having access to your hardware. Maybe you misunderstand the documentation about that interrupt? Maybe it triggers sporadically? Maybe it always triggers the moment you enable it?

Comment: The needed information is not available. I'm assuming `EXT_INT0` is the interrupt handler you speak of? Where and how are you setting this address as being the handler for your button click? What do those other instructions in the RESET do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the interrupt level or edge sensitive? If it is level sensitive, is it sensitive to high or low level? It could happen that your button, when not pressed, leave the interrupt pin with a level so the interrupt is asserted, and when pressed, the interrupt doesn't happen.

Have you tried resetting/powering your system but with the interrupt button pressed all the time? Does the interrupt trigger?